# How to build a menu hook module

Tags: hooks

I am trying to get into module building with Drupal 7.

Why is  `$tryk = "test"` not being taken for the title, but literal strings such as "testmenu" are working?

```
$tryk = "test";
function menufun_menu() {
    global $tryk;
    $items['menufun'] = array(
        'title' => $tryk,
        'page callback' => 'menufun_greeting',
        'file' => 'menufun_greeting.inc',
        'page arguments' => array('Jane', 'Doe'),
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
);
return $items;
}
```

Comment: Have you put `global $tryk` before `$tryk = "test";` ? If not it isn't considered as a global variable.

Comment: The question is about a generic PHP feature, not a Drupal feature (which means the question is probably off-topic here). Module files are included files, and your `$tryk` variable is not global.

Comment: @tostinni, kiamlaluno you are right...it was the global...so shame on me...this is my lack of php knowledge ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use a variable for the page title, it is better to use a title callback.

```
function menufun_menu() {
    $items['menufun'] = array(
        'title callback' => 'menufun_title',
        'page callback' => 'menufun_greeting',
        'file' => 'menufun_greeting.inc',
        'page arguments' => array('Jane', 'Doe'),
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    );
    return $items;
} 
function menufun_title(){
    $tryk = 'test'; // dynamic title set here.
    return $tryk;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer...do you know why it is better to use the callback?

Comment: Because that's the only way ;) the information in hook_menu() is only parsed once and then stored.

Comment: `title` in hook_menu is used for static titles and `title callback` is used to display dynamic titles, such as information from the database.